# C# unmovable dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, garbage-collection

I'm making a data acquisition application in C# that calls a DLL (supplied by DAQ card vendor) and it requires that I register my I/O buffers in that DLL. I have a writing thread that fills the buffer with signal samples. I see a strange behaviour that after some time the output signal becomes noise and I suspect that's because GC has moved my buffers somewhere, so the code in DLL has a pointer to wrong address and outputs junk to DAC.

1) How can I check if I'm right (array has been moved)?

2) If so, how to make an array unmovable? The [Fixed Size Buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx) page at MSDN says I can make a buffer of a fixed size, but I need it to be alocated dynamically (so it can be tuned before acquisition starts).

Comment: [`Marshal.AllocHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal.aspx) may help here.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17610/Pinned-Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use:

```
int[] myarray = new int[1000];

GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(myarray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

Remember to

```
handle.Free();
```

at the end. So if the DLL method spawn a thread and returns immediately, normally it's better to put the handle in a field of the class, not as a local variable.

Note that if you need to make an array live the time of a function call, then you don't need to do it. So for example:

```
int[] myarray = new int[1000];
MyPInvokeMethod(myarray);
```

For the entire life of the `MyPInvokeMethod` the array will be automatically pinned.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] data = new int[size];
GCHandle h = GCHandle Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr ptr = h.AddrOfPinnedObject();

// ptr points to fixed memory which is not moved by GC 
// and can be accessed by unmanaged code

// ...

h.Free();     // now array can be moved
```

Comment: Thanks. So can I use the 'data' variable as before?

Comment: Yes, you can use `data` variable - read and write array members by usual way. All time `GCHandle h` exists and not released, array is unmoveable. You can make `GCHandle h` class member to keep array unmoveable.